# drop down menu doesn't workafter Fooman Speedster uninstall

Tags: module

After uninstalling Fooman speedster the drop down menus and drop down category's no longer works.

Anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

If Speedster is completely uninstalled there is no permanent changes made to your Magento site or theme. I would also suggest browsing your site with an Incognito window to make sure your browser is not using a cached version.

> Uninstallation Instructions
>
> 1. delete the following files/folders:
>    app/etc/modules/Fooman_Speedster.xml
>    app/code/community/Fooman/Speedster
>    lib/minify
>    skin/m
> 2. refresh Magento's cache

It is also possible that you brought to light an issue during the installation since we ask you to refresh the cache during the installation of the extension. This might activate changes you have made before installing Speedster but needed a cache refresh to actually make a difference. Again if all Speedster files have been removed there is no way for them to affect your site's Javascript or CSS.